# how can I fix my website on digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean

I hosted my website on digital ocean and after a few months it stopped working. I can't access my website anymore and when I try to do that I have this page instead
[Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLGIU.png)

tried to login in With SSH connection

Comment: Please contact support at digital ocean.  Also read tour - https://stackoverflow.com/tour